# Como uso a quebra de linha na resposta?

Tags: python-3.x

```
n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())
n3 = int(input())
n0 = (n1, n2, n3)
print(sorted(n0))
```

Eu queria que a resposta saísse uma em cada linha diferente, ou seja, uma abaixo da outra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode capturar os valores e, em seguida, implementar um laço de repetição para exibir o resultado.

O código ficaria:

```
n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())
n3 = int(input())
n0 = sorted((n1, n2, n3))
for c in n0:
    print(c)
print()
```